# Get top level entity based on lower level criteria being met

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have the below database setup.   What I'm hoping to accomplish is to search for a worker in the Worker tabe and return all of the BusinessAreas that the resulting user would fall under per the diagram.  I'm hoping to accomplish this in Lambda expression and return the top level BusinessArea entities.  If need be I could get the workers and through a number of processes get back up to the level I'm wanting but that would require me to iterate through the different levels till I get to the top level.

[image]

Comment: What's your query so far?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have one yet.  I thought I could do something like this but I don't get very far with it because intelsense stops at the end of WorkerProcess as far as my available entities go.

Comment: Sorry hit enter to soon..  Here is what I was talking about.  WFE.Workers.Where(c=>c.UserID == Environment.UserName).Select(c=>c.WorkerProcesses.....)

Comment: This code returns what I want kinda and if need be will.  Workers.Where(c=>c.UserID == "pmarshall").Select(c=>c.WorkerProcesses.Select(d=>d.Process.BusinessArea).Distinct()) It returns all of the processes in a list within one list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like this, to look up the business areas for a single user:

```
var results = WFE.BusinessAreas
    .Where(ba => ba.Processes
        .Any(p => p.WorkerProcesses
            .Any(wp => wp.UserId == "pmarshall")));
```

Or in query syntax:

```
var results =
    from ba in WFE.BusinessAreas
    where ba.Processes.Any(p => p.WorkerProcesses.Any(wp => wp.UserId == "pmarshall"))
    select ba;
```

Or alternatively:

```
var results =
    from ba in WFE.BusinessAreas
    from p in ba.Processes
    from wp in p.WorkerProcesses
    where wp.UserId == "pmarshall"
    select ba;
```

If you'd like to find all areas for all users, you'd want to do something like this:

```
var results =
    (from ba in WFE.BusinessAreas
     from p in ba.Processes
     from wp in p.WorkerProcesses
     select new { ba, wp.UserId })
    .Distinct()
    .ToLookup(x => x.UserId, x => x.ba);
```

And then you can access the results for a single user using `results["pmarshall"]`.